# Akregator fails to retrieve some feeds

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, rss

I am trying to figure this out: Akregator stopped retrieving some of my feeds (such as http://lifehacker.com/vip.xml), even though they used to work, do work in Firefox and some other feeds still do work in Akregator.

I already tried deleting the archives and re-adding the feeds.

Comment: Which version are you using? I'm with 4.10 and the feed you linked works for me.

Comment: I'm using 4.8.4

Comment: I since tried removing and re-installing - didn't help.

Comment: At least some of the feeds (e.g. the one above) work in at least two other feed readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an old version, you could try to update and see if it solves the problem.
It is possible that your issue is a bug solved in more recent versions.

EDIT:
I suggest you to carefully read theses articles about repositories, especially the explanations about third party repos.

http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Kubuntu_Precise_Repositories

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Kubuntu

While using external repositories, keep in mind that the software there could not be properly tested, can have stability issues and cause problems to your systems. Once you have read and understood how repositories work, to upgrade your software, I suggest you to enable the Kubuntu Backports repo, which contains the latest version not only to Akregator but of the full KDE software collection, so be prepared to download a large amount of packages.
An easy way to enable it is with the command `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports`

Comment: It is not listed as a bug, and in any case, I already tried removing and installing the latest compatible version (from Ubuntu software center).

Comment: The official Ubuntu repository for Precise (that's version 12.04) still has the 4.8.4 verison of KDE Software Compilation, while the latest released is 4.10.2. Are you familiar with external repositories?

Comment: No, but I'll make myself familiar with it ;) - will try, thanks.

Comment: I've added to my answer a brief explanation on how to add a repository to upgrade your KDE.

Comment: It didn't work for me (will keep at it next week), but thanks.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, unfortunately I have no more clues.